# Hair particles from the vertex groups inserting into mesh instead of extruding away from mesh

Tags: modeling

[image]

i tested the function on a sphere with proper vertex group and it works just fine, but i assigned different weight to scalps for a head manually with caution but it keeps inserting from the vertex group inside out.

Comment: Are your normals all facing outwards? I'd imagine hair particles emit in the same direction as your normals...

Comment: ya, select the whole head mesh and then push *Shift+N* to recalculate normals.